# Alternatives to expat for stream-oriented XML parsing in C++

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing

Are there alternatives to expat for stream-oriented XML parsing in C++?  The data that I am dealing with arrives over a TCP connection and there are multiple XML documents to deal with, which means I have to reset the XML parser every time there is a new document.  The parser doesn't need to be standards-compliant; I'm interested in being able to parse the XML syntax using a callback-oriented process, rather than conforming to a particular schema.

Comment: What's wrong with expat?

Comment: There's a lot of buffer management and subtle checks one has to do to make it work properly with multiple XML documents coming in as a stream.  Also the errors that it returns when it does fail aren't very helpful.  Perhaps this is just a hard problem for any XML parser, but I'm just want to take a look at any alternatives if there are any.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/igagis/mikroxml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/)?

Comment: Test-driving Xerces-C++ right now.  The API is nice, but I'm not sure whether it will support the kind of streaming that happens over a TCP connection, where I'll receive chunks of data, and many documents and need to reset the XML parsing without losing the spot in the buffer where it left off.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Apache's Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/).